# Plotting pd df with datetime index in Matplotlib results in ValueError due to wrong parsing of datetime values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, formatting

I am trying to plot a `pandas.DataFrame`, but getting an unexplainable ValueError. Here is sample code causing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

weekday_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%a %H:%M')
test_csv = 'datetime,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6\n' \
           '2021-12-06 00:00:00,8,42,14,23,12,2\n' \
           '2021-12-06 00:15:00,17,86,68,86,92,45\n' \
           '2021-12-06 00:30:00,44,49,81,26,2,95\n' \
           '2021-12-06 00:45:00,35,78,33,18,80,67'
test_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(test_csv), index_col=0)
test_df.index = pd.to_datetime(test_df.index)
plt.figure()
ax = test_df.plot()
ax.set_xlabel(f'Weekly aggregation')
ax.set_ylabel('y-label')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12.15, 5)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekday_fmt) # This and the following line are the ones causing the issues
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(weekday_fmt)
plt.show()
```

If the two formatting lines are removed, the code runs through, but if I leave them in there, I get a ValueError: `ValueError: Date ordinal 27312480 converts to 76749-01-12T00:00:00.000000 (using epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00), but Matplotlib dates must be between year 0001 and 9999.`

The reason seems to be that the conversion of datetime in pandas and matplotlib are incompatible. This could probably be circumvented by not using the built-in `plot`-function of pandas. Is there another way? Thanks!

My package versions are:

```
pandas                    1.3.4 
numpy                     1.19.5 
matplotlib                3.4.2 
python                    3.8.10
```

Comment: it looks like the issue is caused by the fact that you have only 1 date, try adding a new row with a different date (`'2021-12-07 00:00:00,35,78,33,18,80,67'`) and it works fine. Not sure why, you should probably report this case to the matplotlib mailing list / tracker to ensure this is not a bug.

Comment: use `ax = test_df.plot(x_compat=True)` to enable compatibility mode for the x axis, i.e. use Python datetime instead of pandas datetime. Thereby, matplotlib can do its job and format correctly. [Example from pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment).

Comment: You can’t mix pandas datetime conversion and matplotlibs locators or formatters.  Use pandas formatters if you are going to use their plotting.

Comment: @mozway: The problem also occured when I had multiple dates. The shown csv-string was only a subsample of what I originally.

Comment: @MrFuppes: The x_compat seems to do the trick, at least in the small test-case. I will try to run it on the larger dataset now, but would expect it to work. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by Jody Klymak and MrFuppes, I found the answer to simply be `ax = test_df.plot(x_compat=True)`. For anybody stumbling upon this in future, here comes the full explanation of what is happening:

When using the plot-function, pandas takes over the formatting of x-tick (and possibly other features). The selected x-tick-values shown to matplotlib do not need to correspond with what one would expect. In the shown example, the function `ax.get_xlim()` returns `(27312480.0, 27312525.0)`. Using `x_compat=True` forces pandas to hand the correct values over to matplotlib where the formatting then happens. Since this was not clear to me from the error message I received, this post might help future viewers searching for that error message.

Comment: I really wonder why this option is so hard to find - pandas docs on [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) don't specify it as it is not part of the [plot accessor class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L620-L1758).

Comment: I agree. Given that I work with pandas daily and matplotlib occasionally, such a fundamental issue should be more apparent, particularly regarding the error message, but I suppose that pandas cannot really send a warning at this point since that is already matplotlib domain. Question remains why pandas doesn't just use matplotlib formatting instead of creating its own world...

Comment: Achieving *really* nice plots with matplotlib requires a lot of fine-tuning in my experience (occasional user as well...), so I see a reason why you'd want to have a good default "pandas-style" formatter. *But* it should be clear from the docs how to disable the default. When I find the time, I'll grep for the kwarg through pandas src code and see if this is worth raising an issue on their github.